# How many times a batsman can stop a bowler while he starts bowling the ball in Cricket? Is there any hard rule/limitation for the batsman?

Tags: rules, cricket

I saw so many times that a batsman stopped the bowler while he is coming to bowl the ball. After he raises his hand bowler stops bowling that ball and he will go back and bowl again. It’s a usual behavior in some matches. But I don’t know whether there is any count limitation for a batsman to stop a bowler in 1 match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no limit - a bowler can stop in his run-up as often as he likes, and a batsman can pull out of a delivery as often as he likes.

In practice, the umpire will have a word if he feels the players are messing about, and it doesn't happen too often.

Note, though, that if a batsman pulls away, and the bowler actually delivers the ball, if the batsman plays at the ball it's considered a stroke, and he can get runs or be out. When umpiring a 20/20 game here I gave out a member of our international team when he slashed at a ball having pulled away, and guided it onto his stumps. He wasn't happy, but he was told by his coach that he was out!

Comment: An international player had to be told of the rule by a coach? Wow!

Comment: You'd be flabbergasted at the lack of knowledge of the laws amongst players, even top-level ones. There's also a large amount of simply wrong impressions out there - for instance, nobody seems to know the only correct way to run out a batsman when the bails are already removed.